# Gradle 2.0 is freezing up from the command line

Tags: gradle

I am running a gradle build via gradlew that has been in existence since before the 1.0 release.  When I run it from the command line:

```
./gradlew build
```

it starts executing one of the Unit Tests and then just freezes.  I am running on a Mac OSX and a recent Java 1.7 release.  Plenty of un-used memory.  The interesting thing is that the build works perfectly well for others here and for the Jenkins job.  Yet, I can not figure out what I might be doing wrong or have set wrong!

If I do:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

it acts exactly the same (only it takes a bit longer!)  Initially GRADLE_OPTS was not set at all, I upped the memory there to 2 GB and the max perm size to 512MB.  Not only does it still freeze, it always freezes in exactly the same place.   The final bit of information is that all the source is pulled from our Git repo - git status shows I have no changes.

As such, I am out of ideas - anyone out there have any?

Comment: Max memory for tests needs to be configured on the test task. "The final bit of information is that all the source is pulled from our Git repo" - this sounds like the problem occurs *outside* the Gradle build.